# virtual function

Tags: java, c++

what are virtual functions? what is pure virtual function? please explain with example

Comment: please at least try searching yourself first...

Comment: @starblue: I think they are generally referred to as abstract in C# and Java.  You say tomato, i say tomato (doesn't quite work in text form).

Comment: No. Java 'abstract' = C++ 'pure virtual'. In Java all instance methods are virtual.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: 'You write color, I write  colour' works better in text... ;)

Comment: I was going to link you to let me google that for you, but apparently that's off-limits here (I'm new to this). So uhhhhhh, maybe I'll just be more civil and say I wholeheartedly agree with Mr. Wheat.

Comment: @EJP: actually, private methods are not virtual.

Answer (score 7):

There's an excellent explanation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Java).

[Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions) between a virtual function and a pure virtual function is that a **virtual function** has an implementation and you have the option to override it.  A **pure virtual function** (abstract in Java) has no implementation and you have to implement it in a subclass (unless your subclass is also abstract).

Comment: I thought that in C++, a virtual function of a derived class will be called even if it is typed as a base class. Is that correct?

Comment: Pure virtual functions can have implementations.  They remain pure, so you still have to provide another implementation in a derived class.  But you can call them if you explicitly state you want the base version.

Comment: @dreamlax: That's the idea behind polymorphism, yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
Virtual Function : A virtual function is a member function that is declared
within a base class and redefined by a derived class.

A base class pointer can be used to point an object of any class derived from
that base. When a base pointer points to a derived object that contains a 
virtual function, C++ determines which version of that function to call based
upon the type of object pointed by the pointer.

*/

#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

class baseclass 
{
    public :
    virtual void vfunc() { cout << "This is base class vfunc\n"; };
};

class derived : public baseclass {
    public :
    void vfunc() { cout << "This is derived class vfunc\n"; };
};

class derived2 : public baseclass {};

int main () 
{
    class baseclass * ptr, b;   // baseclass pointer and its object
    class derived d;        // object of derived class
    class derived2 d2;      // object of derived2 class
    ptr = &b;           // ptr points to baseclass
    ptr->vfunc();       // vfunc of base class will execute
    ptr = &d;           // ptr points to derived class
    ptr->vfunc();       // vfunc of derived class will execute
    ptr = &d2;      // ptr points to derived2 class
    ptr->vfunc();       // vfunc of base class will execute
    return 0;
}    

******************************************************************************

/*
In a Pure Virtual Function, base class have no definition of virtual function
*/

#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

class baseclass 
{
    public :
    virtual void vfunc() = 0 ;  // Pure virtual function
};

class derived : public baseclass {
    public :
    void vfunc() { cout << "This is derived class vfunc\n"; };
};

class derived2 : public baseclass {
    public :
    void vfunc() { cout << "This is derived2 class vfunc\n"; };
};

int main () 
{
    class derived d;        // object of derived class
    class derived2 d2;      // object of derived2 class
    d.vfunc();      // vfunc of derived class will execute
    d2.vfunc();     // vfunc of derived2 class will execute
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you acces a virtual function using dot(.) operator ?